# Wrong format saving XLS files: automatic conversion to numbers

Tags: r, xlsx, xls

I have a string that I need to save as-is in XLS format, but the `WriteXLS` function seems to always convert to a number. The error is also present when opening the xls manually. How can I fix this?

```
nb <- data.frame("92343E102", stringsAsFactors = F)
WriteXLS::WriteXLS(nb, "testdf.xls")
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls")
> read_xls("testdf.xls")
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  X.92343E102.
         <dbl>
1     9.23e106
```

Expected result: `92343E102`

I would need to do so without having python installed if possible, so `dataframes2xls` is not an option for me - appreciate the attemp anyway

Comment: Why not just write to csv then open in excel and save it as xls?

Comment: Trust it or not, I have the same problem. saving as csv using `quote` gives the correct output, however as soon as I open this csv in excel quotes are removed and I get the "+" error again

Comment: That is an excel thing, see my answer below on how to over ride this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I think found a way to avoid XLS conversion of strings like "12E123" to scientific double, which requires no excel interaction using `XLConnect`

```
nb <- data.frame(as.character('92343E102'), stringsAsFactors = F)
WriteXLS::WriteXLS(nb, "testdf.xls")
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls")
wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook("testdf.xls")
XLConnect::createSheet(wb, name="newsheet")
XLConnect::writeWorksheet(wb, nb, sheet = "newsheet")
XLConnect::saveWorkbook(wb)
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls", sheet=1) #converted string to wrong number
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls", sheet=2) # success! string stays string
```

result:

```
> readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls", sheet=1)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  as.character..92343E102..
                      <dbl>
1                  9.23e106
> readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls", sheet=2)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  as.character..92343E102..
  <chr>                    
1 92343E102
```

Of course since I only have 32bit JAVA at work I might have to switch to R32 for this, or write 32bit-R routines to correctly save my XLS files..

One thing at a time... Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

Install the writexl package:

```
 install.packages("devtools", dependencies=TRUE)
# devtools has a _lot_ of dependencies
# it also has a bunch of system tool requirements
 devtools::install_github("ropensci/writexl")
#make a copy of iris
 tmp <- iris
# set [1,1] to your string:
 tmp[1,1] <- "92343E102"  # makes that column 'character'
 tmp2 <- writexl::write_xlsx(tmp)
 readxl::read_xlsx(tmp2)

# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
   <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
 1 92343E102            3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2 4.9                  3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3 4.7                  3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4 4.6                  3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5 5                    3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6 5.4                  3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7 4.6                  3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8 5                    3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9 4.4                  2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10 4.9                  3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I need however I have github firewall-blocked at work, any alternative way to install it? perhaps I should download it home and send it by email to work somehow?

Comment: actually this is for XLSX not for XLS. any solution for XLS?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to you to use `dataframes2xls::write.xls()` instead:

```r
# Make a sample dataframe:
nb <- data.frame(A = "92343E102", B = 92343E102, stringsAsFactors = F)
WriteXLS::WriteXLS(nb, "testdf.xls") # Write out using WriteXLS() ...
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls") # Doesn't work, per your post
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>          A        B
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 9.23e106 9.23e106
# Maybe we can specify what kind of column it is when reading in the data?
readxl::read_xls("testdf.xls", col_types = "text")
# Still doesn't work, it must be the writer
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   A           B          
#>   <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 -2147483648 -2147483648
dataframes2xls::write.xls(nb, "testdf2.xls") # So, try a different writer
readxl::read_xls("testdf2.xls")#, col_types = "text") # Works!
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   A                      B
#>   <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 "\"92343E102\"" 9.23e106
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but then I need to install python, is there any other way? I just edited my question

Comment: Ok, managed to use `dataframes2xls`, but then everything is hard-quoted in excel, how can I remove the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine saving this as a csv, then opening it in Excel.  One option is to use the Get External Data from Text Wizard on the Data Tab. Then select your csv file, configure the appropriate options, and on the third step of the wizard select import as text on the column that has the text in it, as pictured below.  Then you can save this as an .xls and open it again, with out Excel changing the data type to scientific.

[image]

Comment: This is an excel issue not an R issue.  You have several other options for dealing with this, you could put an `=` in front and `"` arround everything, you could manually move things over with `RDCOMClient` package, and there are some other options as well. I just depends on how much time you want to spend on the problem.  I think the answer above is the cleanest I have found.

Comment: Sorry no I think this is an R issue, "how to save this data in this particular format from R", I 100% want to avoid excel

Comment: .xls is an Excel file format so you cant avoid excel.  This is a terrible behavior that excel has.  It does this with dates, CAS numbers, and scientific notation.  Why do you want to put it in xls if you don't want to open it in excel.  Otherwise just use a more generic format.

Comment: I would, if I wasn't depending at work from 10+ year-old java32 software that only uploads xls... I know this point seems stupid but for me it is really blocking. And yes I think I can avoid excel, if I can do it using XLSX why not XLS? just a missing functionality in R or I havent found it yet. Nothing to do with excel!

Comment: When you open an old xls file excel tries to gets smart at that point,  that's why the `write_xlsx` works and the xls does not.  Does the jave read the xls correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183024/discussion-between-ian-wesley-and-gpier).

Comment: I know that it is possible to do in xls because when I paste my column from xlsx into xls, it works: the format is correct into the xls file after copypasting columns from xlsx. So there must be a way to do it from R, without quotes caused by `dataframes2xls`